# Getting the image title/alt attribute from the gallery shortcode

Tags: gallery, images

I am trying to learn how to code php so that I can customize the image gallery within WordPress (among other customizations).

The code I have works great for a stylized gallery page, **but having a difficult time trying to figure out how to get the title and alt attributes of the images within the WP gallery** (I am guessing it's because the images are not seen as attachments to the post since they are in the gallery function).

And I would like to use the WP gallery, as I want to use that WP built-in functionality for galleries.

any help is appreciated... is this the dumbest way of doing something or what?

**Note:** get_attachment or get_children has been disastrous too when trying to edit images on a page when NOT using the WP gallery in that old attachments or children that have been removed from the page still show up).

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="gallery-wrapper three-cols clearfix">

  <?php // image gallery content 
    if( has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) ) {   

       // Add a filter for full gallery size:
       add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery','wpse_full_size_gallery' );


$gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post->ID );

       // Remove the filter:
       remove_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery','wpse_full_size_gallery' );  

foreach ( $gallery as $image_url ) {
        $alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
            $image_title = $attachment->post_title;


            echo '<div class="one-third columns gallery-item">';
            echo '<div class="item-picture" data-type="image">';
            echo '<img src="' . $image_url . '">' ;
            echo '<div class="image-overlay">';
            echo '<a href="' . $image_url . '" data-rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><span class="zoom"></span></a>';
             echo '</div>';
             echo '<span class="item-label">' . $image_title . '</span>';
             echo '</div>';
             echo '</div>';

        }

}                         
?>

  </div>
        <!-- article -->
        <article class="full-width columns" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <br class="clear">

            <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

        </article>
        <!-- /article -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else: ?>

        <!-- article -->
        <article>

            <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h2>

        </article>
        <!-- /article -->

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little background: WP stores the attachments in the same database table as posts. Therefore the table rows correspond to the fields of the media edit modal:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlkpC.jpg]

`get_post_gallery_images` will return you URLs to the images, but not the actual data in the database. You could do a reverse-query and [look for posts that contain the image URL](https://pippinsplugins.com/retrieve-attachment-id-from-image-url/) but that would be more difficult than necessary.

Instead use the [get_post_gallery](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery) function. This one is actually used by `get_post_gallery_images` too, but also returns the IDs of the attachments in an array. Use these IDs to get the information from the database using `get_posts`:

```
<?php
$gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
$args = array( 
    'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_status'    => 'any', 
    'post__in'       => explode( ',', $gallery['ids'] ) 
); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {

    $image_alt = get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    if ( empty( $image_alt )) {
        $image_alt = $attachment->post_title;
    }
    if ( empty( $image_alt )) {
        $image_alt = $attachment->post_excerpt;
    }
    $image_title = $attachment->post_title;
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full' );

    echo '<div class="one-third columns gallery-item">';
    echo '<div class="item-picture" data-type="image">';
    echo '<img src="' . $image_url[0] . '" alt="'. $image_alt .'">' ;
    echo '<div class="image-overlay">';
    echo '<a href="' . $image_url[0] . '" data-rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">
          <span class="zoom"></span></a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<span class="item-label">' . $image_title . '</span>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

} ?>
```

The script looks for alt-tag info in `_wp_attachment_image_alt`, `post_title` and `post_excerpt` until it finds a value.

Comment: Hi Jan thanks so much for your help and augmenting details. Still having trouble getting the gallery images/post-meta, the page returns no results. How does image_url obtain the url of the gallery image? I tried setting `$image_url = post_guid;` to no success. The explode function is taking a string (image IDs) and turning this into an array used by get_posts and get_post_meta, yes? I'm reference the codex too for some clues: [https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery] and [https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image]

Comment: I'm a nut and actually forgot to include image_url. Sorry for that. I have updated the answer. Note that `wp_get_attachment_image_src` returns an array that contains the url, width, height and "boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original or if no image is available."

Comment: Hi Jan, still empty page results. I also tried adding new images to a new gallery to see if I needed to upload new images, not existing images within media library, in order to see if I could get any results, but no. So still learning php but `$image_url[0]` means to set to null until the ID is passed? the only thing that's worked reliably is getting the shortcode for gallery as in my first question, just can't get the darn title.

Comment: So does the counting have to start from 0, can I have an  empty bracket[] and still have image IDs passed though it? `$image_url[0]` vs `$image_url[]`

Comment: I'll try it later, meanwhile have a look at the documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Comment: Terrific! thank you, I finally get it. [0] specifics the first index of the array, the ID. privately I could send you a link to the test page, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. [0] is indeed the first index of the array that contains the direct URL to the image. I ran the code in my dev environment and notices that get_post_gallery needs a second parameter set to `false` otherwise it will not return an array but html of the gallery. I edited the original answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yay! it works! Thank you. -- the code above isn't yet edited, for some reason. But as soon as it is, I'll check the answer as correct.

Comment: should be changed now. Glad I could help you out.

Comment: Greatly appreciated! May I share it?

Comment: Share what? The answer I gave?

Comment: Feel free to do whatever you want with it :)

Comment: Yes, you answer, so much needed and helpful. Thank you.