# How to inject alt and title attributes for every image in each post into HTML?

Tags: images

My sincere apologies if the following is completely way off as I'm new to this.

[This previous answer looks like what I'm trying to find, but I'm not sure what to do with this information.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/how-to-retrieve-an-image-attachments-alt-text)

From what I can tell, I need to be working with `wp_get_attachment_image` to inject the alt and title text for every image in every post.

My theme is loading in post content with `the_content();`, and after looking at the [Wordpress Developer page for `the_content();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) I'm guessing that this function is calling `post-template.php`.

The only section I can find in `post-template.php` that contains `wp_get_attachment_image` is as follows:

```
if ( $text ) {
    $link_text = $text;
} elseif ( $size && 'none' != $size ) {
    $link_text = wp_get_attachment_image( $_post->ID, $size, $icon, $attr );
} else {
    $link_text = '';
}
```

[After looking over this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193196/how-to-get-image-title-alt-attribute), I'm guessing I need to do something like this with the above code:

```
if ( $text ) {
    $link_text = $text;
} elseif ( $size && 'none' != $size ) {
    $image_alt = get_post_meta( $image->id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    $link_text = wp_get_attachment_image( $_post->ID, $size, $icon, $image_alt );
} else {
    $link_text = '';
}
```

I've passed the variable `$image_alt` in place of `$attr` here.

Again, I imagine this is very wrong, and my apologies.

Comment: Once an image is inserted into content it's hardcoded there as an HTML tag. If you want to add alt text you need to parse the content, insert the tags into the HTML and update the post. `wp_get_attachment_image()` won't be involved. That function is for use in templates.

Comment: Wouldn't I use that function since I want this behavior default across the entire theme?

Comment: When you add an image to a post it is added as HTML with the alt attribute that you give it when inserting the image. So having alt text in content *is* the default behaviour. What I'm saying is it's not possible to automatically update post content when the alt text of an image is changed in the media library without parsing the post content and modifying the HTML.

Comment: Aaaaaaaah that makes sense. It's because I added the meta data after already posting. Thank you