# How can I add "alt" tag to <picture> element?

Tags: images

I am developing my own theme and for logo I use  tag:

```
<?php
   $image_url = get_theme_mod( 'header_logo_image_home', '' );
   $image_id = attachment_url_to_postid($image_url );
?>
   <picture class="lozad" data-src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'logo' )[0]; ?> 1x, <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'logo-retina' )[0]; ?>  2x" data-alt="====> ? HOW ? <====">
   <source srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'logo' )[0]; ?>  1x, <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'logo-retina' )[0]; ?>  2x">
   </picture>
```

Is there any way do get ALT based on 'attachment_url_to_postid'?

PS: I use  element with lozad.js lazyload script.

Thanks!

Comment: Question: why did you type `data-alt` instead of just `alt`?

Comment: It's part of lozad.js...

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that :) I haven't used lozad.js before. Have you tried this: `$image_alt = get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);`? It's from another answer to a similar question here: [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/330599/160457](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/330599/160457).

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. Perhaps you can give the original posters of that thread an up-vote so others can find it, too? [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/330599/160457](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/330599/160457)