# All Images not calling alt text

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, accessibility

I am having trouble with the alt text on my wordpress.com website. I am using a theme I coded myself. From what I recall, if I added alt text to an image in the Media Library it would insert into the DOM. Whether I'm mistaken or not, I do know no alt text is being added to the DOM now. Below is a code sample of a image I am calling. I do not call  `alt` because I believed WordPress automatically added it, and if it doesn't I do not know what to put in it's place. Clarification is appreciated.

*Edit:* To resolve a flag of a duplicate, my question revolves around using the_post_thumbnail to call the image. I am indeed using the_post_thumbnail_url which I need to change to the_post_thumbnail but this causes the images to disappear. In the suggested duplicate question, the alt needs to be called manually where-as I am looking for it to be called automatically.

**Image code sample**

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" class="img-responsive">
```

**I tried adding this code to functions.php during my research but it did not work:**

```
function add_img_title($attr, $attachment = null) {
$img_title = trim(strip_tags($attachment->post_title));
$attr['alt'] = $img_title;
$attr['title'] = $img_title;
return $attr;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'add_img_title', 10, 2);
```

**Update**

After receiving feedback to change `the_post_thumbnail_url` to `the_post_thumbnail` I have decided to include the wp_query and the loop as I am having trouble calling images via `the_post_thumbnail`

```
<?php 
 $query1 = new WP_Query(array(
      'cat' => 162,
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'posts_per_page' => 1
  ));

  $query2 = new WP_Query(array(
      'cat' => 162,
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 1
  ));

  $wp_query = new WP_Query();
  $wp_query->posts = array_merge( $query1->posts, $query2->posts );
  $wp_query->post_count = $query1->post_count + $query2->post_count;
?>
<?php while( $wp_query->have_posts() ): $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
  <?php  $id = get_the_ID(); ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get image title/alt attribute?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193196/how-to-get-image-title-alt-attribute)

Comment: Still not getting image alt with the update?

Comment: " I am having trouble calling images via the_post_thumbnail" Are you getting the image at least? If you're getting an image but no alt text then it means you haven't provided any alt text in the media library.

Answer (score 1):

You're not outputting any attributes besides the src and class. Try using `the_post_thumbnail()` instead.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); ?>
```

This will include all attributes and supports responsive image markup by default.

Comment: You're correct, I should have been using the_post_thumbnail. However I tried adding this and now the images have disappeared. I even tried removing everything in between the parenthesis as a test and the images still do not display. I do have: `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` in my functions.php

Comment: This function must be in the loop. Otherwise, you should use `echo get_the_post_thumbnail()` and pass in the post ID.

Comment: I updated my question which includes my query and loop. Right now my the_post_thumbnail is in the while loop so I am unsure why it is not being called. I thought adding the query and loop would aid in resolving this

Comment: You have a strange loop. You should probably explicitly use `echo get_the_post_thumbnail()` with the correct ID.